# link doesnot changes when images changes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
     <?php
$r=array(array("img_name"=>"6.png","link"=>"<a href='http://southpacifiv.com/BA_Hons_Business_Management.php' target='_blank'>"),
        array("img_name"=>"7.png","link"=>"<a href='http://southpacifiv.com/MBA.php' target='_blank'>"),
        array("img_name"=>"11.png","link"=>"<a href='http://southpacifiv.com/why.php' target='_blank'>"),
        array("img_name"=>"10.png","link"=>"<a href='#' onclick='moregvid()'>"),
        array("img_name"=>"9.png","link"=>"<a href='http://southpacifiv.com/courseMain.php' target='_blank'>")
);
?>
       <div id="slideshow">

          <?php
          for($i=0;$i<count($r);$i++) {
            echo'<div>';
          echo ''.$r[$i]['link'].'<div  style="background:url('.$img_loc.''.$r[$i]['img_name'].') no-repeat top center;"></div></a>';
           echo'</div>';
          }
          ?>

        </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(5000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(5000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  10000);

});
</script>
```

my problem is that , i have 5 images in my array and a link to the specific page when the images changes the link also changes , but the link changes after 3 sec when the image i already change . So if a user change on the any of the image , it can redirect to the wrong page if the user click on in between 3 sec

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code it seems to be working fine. I guess there might be some other issue other than the code you have given here..

Comment: if the transition happen between 1st and 2nd image ,and its showing 2nd image for 3 sec it will show u 1st image url